# Radio button bind shortcut by Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two radio button in my GUI and I want to print my selection when I press 'q' or 'w'. (shortcut)

```
import tkinter as tk


def print_selection(*event):
    l.config(text='you have selected ' + var.get())


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x200")

var = tk.StringVar()
l = tk.Label(win, width=20, text='empty')
l.pack()

var.set('...')
r1 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text='A', variable=var, value='A', command=print_selection)
r1.pack()
r2 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text='B', variable=var, value='B', command=print_selection)
r2.pack()

r1.bind_all('<q>', print_selection)  # press 'q' to show message
r2.bind_all('<w>', print_selection)  # press 'w' to show message
win.mainloop()
```

The **label l** show **you have selected...** when I press 'q' or ''w but I want **label l** to show **you have selected A** or **you have selected B**. How to solve it.

Comment: Can you clarify the behavior you want please? At the moment your app seems to do exactly what you say.

Comment: `command=print_selection` won't pass your StringVar.  Instead, try: `command=lambda: print_selection(var)`.

Comment: Similarly, neither will bind_all -- bind_all *will* pass the event though.  So maybe you want to use `print_selection(*event, var=None)`, `command=lambda: print_selection(var=var)` and `.bind_all('<key>', lambda e: print_selection(e, var=var)`.